# Is it possible $\lVert a\rVert =\lVert 1+a\rVert $ in a C$^*$-algebra?

Tags: c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a unital C$^*$-algebra and $a\in A$,  Is it possible $
\lVert a \rVert =\lVert 1+a \rVert $ for an $a\geq 0$  ?

I think it's trivial that it's not possible  but I can't  prove it for even $ 
A=Mat_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})! $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly not possible for $a\geq 0$ since $\lVert x\rVert=\sup \sigma(x)$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\sigma(1+a)=1+\sigma(a)$.